# How to get all tests to run names from NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

We have set of around 1500 tests, and this number is growing fast. We want to split dynamically between several machines to avoid doing it manually each time we have new set of tests.

The problem is some of the tests are data driven, so we can see only one test in run time via reflection. However, NUnit creates multiple tests based on the parameters given in the `TestCaseSource`.

How can we access the list of tests to run as presented in the test explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your tests from the NUnit console runner with the `--explore` command line option and pipe the output to a file.

```
nunit3-console.exe --explore test.dll > testlist.txt
```